# Deque index-iterator conversion

Tags: c++, iterator, deque

Say I have deque element index "i". Deque allows element access by index in constant time. So it looks like we can quickly find element position in memory. But when it comes to get an iterator (to pass to erase() for example), we need to make begin() + i which will take linear time. Is it possible to convert index -> iterator in constant time? If not what's the difference between indexing/creating an iterator? Is the opposite operation possible: pointer to element/iterator -> index (without iterating to the begin/end)?

Comment: Why do you think `begin() + i` takes linear time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we need to make begin() + i which will take linear time.

No it won't.

Iterators that support `operator+` should do it in constant time (this is true for the standard iterators, user-defined iterators could define `operator+` that is linear, but that would be unconventional).

Iterators that don't support it in constant time need to be advanced with `std::advance` not `operator+`

`std::deque::iterator` is a random-access iterator, so `begin() + i` is valid and takes constant-time.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to convert index -> iterator in constant time?

Yes.

```
iter = deq.begin() + index;
```

This is constant time, contrary to your belief. Any iterator in the standard library (or designed by the same philosophy as the standard library) which supports `operator+`, does so in constant time. In fact, all operators which act on standard library iterators are constant time. Any operator which cannot be implemented in constant time is not implemented. This is why only random access iterators (`vector`, `deque`, `string`, etc...) support operations like addition with an integer, or subtraction from each other.

> Is the opposite operation possible: pointer to element/iterator -> index

Yes.

```
index = iter - deq.begin();
```

This is also constant time.